# Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

**I'm using hibernate to store a Student object which is having an embedded type Address object. I'm using a form to get inputs name, city, state. City & State getting null while submitting the form how to capture these values in Model Object. ${student.homeAddress.city} - This value is NULL**

Issue Resolved!

[image]

```
public class Student {

@Id
@Column(name = "student_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "students_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "students_seq", name = "students_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private int studentId;

@Column(name = "student_name")
private String studentName;

@Embedded
private Address homeAddress;
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
StudentService studentService;

@RequestMapping("/registrationForm")
public String showFormForStudentRegistration(Model model) {

    Student studentObj = new Student();
    Address addressObj = new Address();
    studentObj.setHomeAddress(addressObj);
    model.addAttribute("student", studentObj);
    return "student-form";
}

@RequestMapping("/register")
public String registerStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
    
    studentService.createStudent(student);
    return "student-success";
    
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: what are you expecting from `@Embaded` ? what is the data source you working with ?

Comment: I have 3 fields on my form. Name, City, State. Name is from Student. City and State from Address respectively. If I give values and submit the form. I'm getting NullPointerException due to City, State values are not captured from form. I dont know how to capture those.

Answer (score 0):

**${student.address.state} -> This is how needs to be accessed after submitting it. when submitting form it should be like this <form:input path="address.state" **
Data successfully inserted.

[image]